# Spring MVC configuration with java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using `Apache Tomcat 7.0.54` and `Spring MVC 4.0.1` and trying to configure `DispatcherServlet` with `Java`:
I've written the config class:

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected WebApplicationContext createServletApplicationContext() {
        XmlWebApplicationContext context = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation("/WEB-INF/her-servlet.xml");
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"*.her"};
    }

    @Override
    protected WebApplicationContext createRootApplicationContext() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and it doesn't work. But if I write the follwoing:

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{


    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext sc) throws ServletException {
        XmlWebApplicationContext context = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation("/WEB-INF/her-servlet.xml");
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = sc.addServlet("her", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registration.addMapping("*.her");
    }

}
```

It'll work fine. I don't understand the problem. Could you help me to solve?

Comment: Inline code spans (`gray` things) are usually used for strings recognized or generated by a computer. Not for product names like Apache. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215595/245518) for details.

Comment: I would advise you to use the approach from this post: http://www.joshlong.com/jl/blogPost/simplified_web_configuration_with_spring.html. In other words, do not set up your application context in `onStartup`---and do not use XML-based application context configuration.